# FPDF: Local saved pdfs are damaged

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I've got a project where we output some data as pdf in the browser. The user also can download the pdf directly. If we run the project on our local machine the pdf creation and the view works without problems.

But if we put the project online we've got a problem that the pdf which is generated by FPDF is damaged. The code is 100% the same code as it runs local. So we think its a server problem ?

Facts (Online):

- Firefox - View: OK - Save: Damaged
- IE - View: OK - Save: Damaged
- Chrome - View: Error - Save: not working

Does anybody have the same problems?

I don't know which code I should present you cause it's too much to show.
After all pdf-creation stuff I just do the output:

```
 $pdf->AddFooter(1);
 unset($_SESSION['projektId']);
 $pdf->SetTitle(((isset($client['benutzer']))? $client['benutzer'].' | ':'').(isset($client['name'])? $client['name']:'').' | Name | '.$monat.'/'.$jahr, 1);
 $pdf->Output('F', $this->config->item('dir').'/folder/name'.$user.'_'.$year.'_'.str_pad($month, 2, "0").'.pdf');
 return $pdf->Output('I', 'name'.$user.'_'.$year.'_'.str_pad($month, 2, "0").'.pdf');
```

I don't have much experience with *FPDF*. So I am happy to hear from you.

Comment: what do you mean by damaged? does it no appear at all, or does is do not render some elements as expected?

Comment: By the way: return $pdf->Output('I', 'name'.$user.'_'.$year.'_'.str_pad($month, 2, "0").'.pdf'); does not make much sense, as you "echoing" the content to standard output....

Comment: Can you show a damaged version? You may try to change the $dest parameter to "D" to bypass the inline PDF viewer. Are you using encrpytion/protection?

Comment: Hi sorry I was not in the office until today. 
With damaged I mean the PDF is not appearing in the browser (Error-Message: Error loading the pdf.) -> not more and if I download it and try to open it in the acrobat reader I'll get the message that its damaged. So I opened it in the Notepad and I acctually see the error in the pdf:

Before the Version "%PDF-1.4" is starting fpdf is printing my footer as Metahead: 

BT /F1 7.00 Tf ET
q 0.561 0.561 0.561 rg BT 45.35 55.60 Td (.. much more text ) Tj ET 
Q%PDF-1.4... 

(I couldnt paste all the header text here)

How can I delete this tex?

Comment: Cause when I delete it and open it again it works.